# Android - getTabHost() not recognizing

Tags: java, android

i am trying to add tabs with two url open on click .

> MainActivity.java

```
 package com.example.notification;

 import android.app.TabActivity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.res.Resources;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.widget.TabHost;

 public class MainActivity extends TabActivity{
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     TabHost host=getTabHost();

     host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("g")
     .setIndicator("Google")
     .setContent(new Intent(this, WebActivity2.class)));
     host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("y")
     .setIndicator("Yahoo")
     .setContent(new Intent(this, WebActivity3.class)));
     }
 }
```

here are two url java files

> WebAcitivity2.java

```
 package com.example.notification;

 import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.webkit.WebView;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class WebActivity2 extends Activity {
    WebView browser;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        WebView browser = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(browser);
        browser.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

and

> WebAcitivity2.java

```
 package com.example.notification;

 import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.webkit.WebView;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class WebActivity3 extends Activity {
    WebView browser;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        WebView browser = new WebView(this);
        setContent`enter code here`View(browser);
        browser.loadUrl("http://www.yahoo.com");
    }
}
```

i dont understand why its not working as i check all codes are build same as above.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: @hichris123 app is crashing i find out it cloud be due to      TabHost host=getTabHost();

Comment: Kindly post your xml file for MainActivity.java. Secondly I review your code you didn't use `setContentView(R.layour.your_layout_name);` in MainActivity class may be that's why your application is crashing.